# Code works inside of class but doesn't work as library

Tags: c#, .net, sapi

I'm working with sapi and trying to make simple console application.

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var uniq = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + ".wav";

            string filename = @"C:\Users\Денис\Desktop\" + uniq; 
            var voc = new Vocalizer("Vocalizer for Enterprise Milena 22kHz");
            var sw = new Stopwatch();
            sw.Start();
            for (int i = 0; i < 2000; i++)
            {
                voc.SpeakToFile("testphrase", filename);
                Console.WriteLine((i + 1) + "times recorded.");
            }
            sw.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine(sw.Elapsed);
        }
    }
```

And here is code of class:

```
public class Vocalizer
    {
        private SpeechVoiceSpeakFlags _spFlags = SpeechVoiceSpeakFlags.SVSFlagsAsync;
        private SpVoice _speaker = new SpVoice();

        public Vocalizer(string vocalizerString)
        {
            _speaker.Voice = _speaker.GetVoices().Cast<SpObjectToken>().Single(vo => vo.GetDescription() == vocalizerString);
        }

        public void SpeakToFile(string phrase, string filepath)
        {
            var spFileMode = SpeechStreamFileMode.SSFMCreateForWrite;
            var spFileStream = new SpFileStream();
            spFileStream.Open(filepath, spFileMode, false);

            _speaker.AudioOutputStream = spFileStream;
            _speaker.Speak(phrase, _spFlags);
            _speaker.WaitUntilDone(Timeout.Infinite);

            spFileStream.Close();
        }
    }
```

The problem is: if I run my app from VS with attached debugger it works fine (no matter Debug or Release version).
However if I'm trying to run it outside of VS or without debugger attached, it freezes there

```
_speaker.AudioOutputStream = spFileStream;
```

without errors, messages, warning or exceptions.
The last thing I discovered through my trials is that application works as it should without debugger attached if I place function code (SpeakToFile) of class in my console application, but that's not solution as it should be separate class library.

I'm using custom vocalizer Mileena (nuance).
Default Windows preinstalled vocalizers work fine with my app.

Comment: This is probably a deadlock caused by your program not calling Application.Run(), very important to single-threaded COM servers.  See if you get a repro by putting [STAThread] on the Main() method of your console mode app.

Comment: @HansPassant It works! I wish I could mark you commet as answer.